# Pass input text value to controller on button click in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am learning LWC and I want to pass input text value to controller on a button click. Please help.

**Please Note:**

> I can retrieve the value using onchange function on input as below:

```
<lightning-input type="text" name="input1" label="Enter a Value" onchange={handleInput}> </lightning-input>
```

> But, I want to retrieve text value on button click:

```
<lightning-button label="Show Value" onclick={showRefreshVal}></lightning-button>
```

My code so far:

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="text" name="input1" label="Enter a Value" value={parentVal}> </lightning-input>
            <lightning-button label="Show Value" onclick={showRefreshVal}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class ApiFunction extends LightningElement {
    parentVal;
    showRefreshVal() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log("this.parentVal: ", this.parentVal);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> this.parentVal:  undefined

**Expected OUTPUT**

> this.parentVal:  [value typed on input text]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data binding is one way in Lightning. What you want to do is just ask the component what the value is. Here's an [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/hiNBWxL9/1/edit):

```
<template>
    <lightning-input label="Demo">
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="Update Value" onclick={updateText}>
    </lightning-button>
    <hr />
    {outputText}
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track outputText;
    updateText(event) {
        this.outputText = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;
    }
}
```

---

We can grab the lightning input via querySelector, then get the `.value` from there. You can set a name or other unique attribute to find a specific input from the available inputs if you need to.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox
I have made a small change in the playground, 1. Implemented it with a unique name property. 2. Removed Track from JS, as it's not mandatory. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/hiNBWxL9/2/edit

Comment: Alternatively, you could add an onchange / oncommit function attribute to your `lightning-input` element which would update `parentVal`.

Comment: Thanks for the great example! My question is in cases like your example where I want to get the input value in my JS after a button has been clicked, is it the only way? and the best way, to use 'this.template.querySelector()' to get that value? I'm thankful you are in this platform @sfdcfox! Have a great Thanksgiving weekend!!

Comment: @Bahman.A You can choose to not get the value until you need it; for example, you could do `let myValue = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;` There's also querySelectorAll if you need to get multiple elements. If you want more than a comment, you can always ask a new question, I'd be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the quick response. I’d like to understand all the different ways I can collect input data in JS after a button click. I understand that this is something I need to create a new question for.